# Errors in simple bash script

Tags: bash, raspberry-pi

So I have a small bash script that is working on my pi, but for some reason is kicking out errors on a friends pi.

What the end goal is a file to be downloaded and renamed to be used by another script.  This happens 4 times a day so part of the script removes the previous file before it starts.  It then downloads the new file and then renames it so the other script can reference one file instead of all four that get downloaded throughout the day.

Here is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -r /NeoSectional/GFSMAV &
sudo wget https://www.weather.gov/source/mdl/MOS/GFSMAV.t00z -P /NeoSectional/
sleep 5
sudo mv /NeoSectional/GFSMAV.t00z /NeoSectional/GFSMAV
```

So it should remove the file GFSMAV

Then download the new file GFSMAV.t00z and place it into the NeoSectional directory

Wait five seconds

Then change the name from GFSMAV.t00z to GFSMAV

Here is what I get as an output on my friends pi.

```
getmos0.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
getmos0.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found
--2020-04-22 11:50:03--  https://www.weather.gov/source/mdl/MOS/GFSMAV.t18z
Resolving www.weather.gov (www.weather.gov)... 23.1.244.20, 2600:1406:3c:498::116,     2600:1406:3c:497::116
Connecting to www.weather.gov (www.weather.gov)|23.1.244.20|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3198792 (3.0M) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/NeoSectional/\r/GFSMAV.t18z.1’

GFSMAV.t18z.1                     100%   [============================================================>]   3.05M  1.72MB/s    in 1.8s    

2020-04-22 11:50:05 (1.72 MB/s) - ‘/NeoSectional/\r/GFSMAV.t18z.1’ saved [3198792/3198792]

sleep: invalid time interval ‘5\r’
Try 'sleep --help' for more information.
mv: cannot stat '/NeoSectional/GFSMAV.t18z': No such file or directory
```

For some reason it ends up creating a directory called  ''$'\r'

Also it errors out on the removing of the file, it tries to put the file in /NeoSectinoal/\r/, and then since it puts it in that odd directory it mv at the end.

We have chmod +x the bash file.

Any ideas what is going on here?

THANKS

Comment: Have you edited the file on windows? Try to remove the newline after the `sleep 5` command and re-add it (in linux/on the raspberry pi).

Comment: And run the file through `fromdos`.

Comment: Or run `cat getmos0.sh | sed 's/\r$//' > tmp;mv tmp getmos0.sh`. This removes all `\r`s

Comment: @dan1st Edited in SublimeText on a mac.

Comment: A mac uses `\n` so it should work.

Comment: @dan1st Cat getmos0.sh gives me -bash: tmp: Permission denied
mv: cannot stat 'tmp': No such file or directory

Comment: Are you in the same directory where the file is? Do you have the necessary permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is clear for you from the comments above that your file `getmos0.sh` contains `\r\n` (carriage return and line feed) at the end of each line as in MS-DOS, instead of `\n` (line feed) only as in Unix and Linux.

The answers they gave to you have that as goal. A shorter way to remove all the `\r` from your file, without creating a temporary file `tmp` is:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' getmos0.sh
```

Comment: When viewing the file in nano on the pi I don't see anything at the end of the lines.  Would it be visible in nano?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is line separation.

Windows terminates each line using a line feed(`\n`) and a carriage return(`\r`)(two characters) while linux does only use line feeds.

The problem most likely occured when copying the file from windows to the Raspberry Pi. This lept the `\r`s and bash could not understand it when you tried to execute it.

You can do one of the following

- open the file on the raspberry pi with a text editor, remove all weird characters at the end of lines(especially sonething like `^M` or `\n`) if there are any, delete the newlines and create it again(in the editor)
- Remove all `\r`s automatically using a command like `cat getmos0.sh | sed 's/\r$//' > tmp;mv tmp getmos0.sh`.
- If `fromdos` is installed, you can just run `fromdos getmos0.sh`. See the comment from @Roadowl.

You need to be in the same directory as the script and have write permissions in order to use those solutions.